# hibernate many to many mapping using unique column (not primary key)

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 table with many to many association

Table `A`:

```
ID (PK), A_NAME
```

Table `B`:

```
ID (PK), B_CODE(UNIQUE), B_NAME
```

Table `A_B`:

```
ID (PK), ID (FK to table A(ID)), CODE (FK to table B(B_CODE))
```

I want to configure a hibernate class using an annotation for this many to many relationship. The problem is that table `A_B` has `CODE` (is FK to table `B(B_CODE))` but `B_CODE` is not a primary key. My previous attempts have failed.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution :

Table SCHEME :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCHEME")
public class Scheme implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "SCHEME_NAME")
    private String schemeName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "POSITION_SCHEME", 
             joinColumns = {
                  @JoinColumn(name = "SCHEME_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
             inverseJoinColumns = {
                  @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")}
    )
    private Set<Position> positions = new HashSet<>();
    // getter & setter
}
```

Table POSITION :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSITION")
public class Position implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "POSITION_DESCRIPTION")
    private String positionDescription;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "POSITION_SCHEME", 
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "SCHEME_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private Set<Scheme> schemes = new HashSet<>();
}
```